# Добрый вечер, подскажите регулярное выражение, как из текста излечь число из 8 цифр, начинающиеся на 0

Tags: регулярные-выражения

Есть такая строка "Ведомость номер кшп00001759"

Как из текста излечь только число из 8 цифр, начинающиеся на 0., И как вместе с буквами.

Comment: ```0\d{7}``` собсно...

Comment: и как-то так `\b([а-я]+0\d{7})\b` для букв

Comment: Добавить негативные проверки по обе стороны на отсутствие цифр к варианту Akina и готово

Comment: Спасибо большое,  получилось

Answer (score 1):

Конкретно для вашего примера (не знаю, сколько букв бывает в номере):

```
\s([а-я]+)(0\d{7})\g
```

В первой группе будут буквы номера, во второй цифры номера.

Демо: https://regex101.com/r/0JLz8n/1

Если ровно три буквы бывает, то можно уточнить:

```
\s([а-я]{3})(0\d{7})\g
```

Comment: Спасибо большое,  получилось